# Вызов OnNothingSelected при выходе из диалогового окна в Spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-dialog

У меня есть в `activity` `Spinner`, который открывается в диалоговом окне с помощью `android:spinnerMode="dialog"`.

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    style="@style/spinner_style"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog"/>
```

Когда я нажимаю, при открытом "диалоге", в сторону, на активность, пространство вне диалогового окна, диалог закрывается.
Можно ли, при закрытии этого диалог.окна нажатием на пространство вне окна вызывать метод наподобии `OnNothingSelected`, который находится в `setOnItemSelectedListener` в `Spinner`?

Можно ли и как вообще вызывать метод, при выходе из диалогового окна вышеуказанным способом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Увы, у `Spinner'а` эти моменты нельзя отследить. Как вариант можно использовать `Button` + `AlertDialog` заместо `Spinner'a`.

Например так:

```
AlertDialog.Builder b = new Builder(this);
b.setTitle("Example");
ListAdapter adapter = ....;
b.setAdapter(adapter, new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position) {

    }

});

b.show();
```

Можно слушать момент отмены:

```
b.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {

        }
    })
```

И закрытия:

```
b.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Зачем `Button`? кнопка это `TextView` с бэкграундом. Достаточно обычного `TextView` со стилем от `Spinner`, при выборе из списка значение по позиции выводить в этот `TextView`/ Будет то же самое, что `Spinner` в режиме `DialogMode`

Comment: @pavlofff согласен, это не принципиально :)

Comment: @pavlofff, а можете, пожалуйста, показать как это реализовать с TextView?

Comment: @zTrap, а не могли бы вы мне немного помочь, в плане кода и его структуры, пожалуйста? У меня в приложении динамически создается список `textview`. У каждого я обрабытываю с помощью листнера нажатие - `OnClick`, при котором к базе идет запрос и я получаю список значений.  Каким образом, при нажатии на `textview` и получении результата запроса на экран выводить `AlertDialog` с этим списком, или как сказал pavloff - выпадающий список в режиме `Dialog` как у `Spinner`? Не понимаю как это написать корректно

Comment: @lcnw Если у вас появилась новая проблема, которую вы не можете решить самостоятельно, создайте новый вопрос. Этот вопрос к описываемым вами проблемам не имеет никакого отношения.

Answer (score -1):

[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18636385) пример унаследованного Spinner, которому можно передать listener и слушать события открытия/закрытия спиннера.

Сам код:

```
publiс class CustomSpinner extends Spinner {

/**
* An interface which a client of this Spinner could use to receive
* open/closed events for this Spinner. 
*/
public interface OnSpinnerEventsListener {

    /**
     * Callback triggered when the spinner was opened.
     */
     void onSpinnerOpened(Spinner spinner);

    /**
     * Callback triggered when the spinner was closed.
     */
     void onSpinnerClosed(Spinner spinner);

}

private OnSpinnerEventsListener mListener;
private boolean mOpenInitiated = false;

// implement the Spinner constructors that you need

@Override
public boolean performClick() {
    // register that the Spinner was opened so we have a status
    // indicator for when the container holding this Spinner may lose focus
    mOpenInitiated = true;
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onSpinnerOpened(this);
    }
    return super.performClick();
}

/**
* Register the listener which will listen for events.
*/
public void setSpinnerEventsListener(
        OnSpinnerEventsListener onSpinnerEventsListener) {
    mListener = onSpinnerEventsListener;
}

/**
 * Propagate the closed Spinner event to the listener from outside if needed.
 */
public void performClosedEvent() {
    mOpenInitiated = false;
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onSpinnerClosed(this);
    }
}

/**
 * A boolean flag indicating that the Spinner triggered an open event.
 * 
 * @return true for opened Spinner 
 */
public boolean hasBeenOpened() {
    return mOpenInitiated;
}

public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus) {
    if (hasBeenOpened() && hasFocus) {
        performClosedEvent();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: в разметке менять ничего не надо? Как был Spinner, так он и остается? Меняется только в коде, где вместо типа Spinner нужно использовать CustomSpinner, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @Icnw, в разметке надо заменить `Spinner` на `com.example.package.CustomSpinner` (замените на Ваш пакет). В коде да, используйте `CustomSpinner` и ему передавайте `OnSpinnerEventsListener`